# What is the name of this graph theory concept?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, relations

I'm writing notes for my discrete math students and I'm trying to explain transitivity. There's a theorem I want to write down, but I'm not sure if there is a standard name for the object I construct.

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $X$ and let us call a **path** a finite sequence $x_1x_2 \ldots x_n$ where $x_i$ is related to $x_{i+1}$. If $R$ is transitive then each path has the property that $x_1$ is related to $x_n$.

I'd like to say, "In a transitive relation every path is [blank]." I'm not sure what goes in the blank, if there is standard terminology for a path whose beginning is connected by a directed edge to its end. It's not a circuit, since it's not the case that $x_n$ is related to $x_1$ necessarily. It's not just "closed," is it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I apologize if my wording is unclear. I mean to ask if there is a standard name for a directed path $x_1 \to x_2 \to \cdots \to x_n$ where there is also a directed edge $x_1 \to x_n$.

Comment: Do you mean an equivalence relation? On the vertices? The phrasing is super weird.

Comment: No. I have an arbitrary transitive relation. In a transitive relation, every path (defined in my question, but it's a chain of pairwise related elements) must have the additional property that the beginning of the path is related to the end of the path. I am wondering if there is a standard name for a path whose beginning is connected by a directed edge to its end.

Comment: When R is transitive, the path is a  total relation.  The description of the theorem needs to be improved so it appears written by a teacher or a professor instead of a student.

Comment: Sure. I am asking, specifically, if there is a name in graph theory for a path $x_1\to x_2 \to ... \to x_n$ where also $x_1 \to x_n$.

Comment: Mixing relations with graphs is an inferior activity.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Yikes ... I don't think that is a thing OP.

Comment: Thanks @DonThousand, I wasn't sure it was when I wrote the question.

Comment: @DouglasWeathers No problem. Also, please don't get offended by any comments here, we get a ton of crap questions, we can get a little irritable.

Comment: *Your* comments were fine, I agree that my phrasing was not entirely clear. I should have dropped the context and just asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't call it closed.  Closed paths are already a different thing.  If I were writing your notes, I'd say that every path was "shortcutable" ("shortcuttable"?) and try to use that word as infrequently as possible.  At least it would help with visualization.  Proper graph theory vocabulary will not particularly help you here, because a graph with that property is formally called ... transitive.

(And I for one applaud tying relations to directed graphs.  The payoff when you show that the directed graphs of equivalence relations is a union of complete graphs will make it super-obvious how they are related to partitions!)